# can't find my element (selenium beginner)

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception

new programmer here- 
I am trying to make a cookieclicker bot using selenium. Cookie clicker is a website game linked below

http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

I am attempting to locate the element, like so

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("upgrades"));
```

and then I call it here:

```
upgrades = element.findElements(By.className("enabled"));
```

I want to make a list of "upgrades" that are "enabled". However, I get a null pointer exception on the second piece of code- but on the website there clearly is an element called "upgrades".

Thank you for your time!

edit:

this is the block of code from the game that I am trying to click

```html
<div id="upgrades" class="storeSection upgradeBox"><div onclick="Game.UpgradesById[0].click(event);" class="crate upgrade enabled" onmouseout="Game.setOnCrate(0);Game.tooltip.shouldHide=1;" onmouseover="if (!Game.mouseDown)
```

and I am trying to fish out these "enabled" upgrades

```html
<div onclick="Game.UpgradesById[0].click(event);" class="crate upgrade enabled" onmouseout="Game.setOnCrate(0);Game.tooltip.shouldHide=1;" onmouseover="if (!Game.mouseDown) {Game.setOnCrate(this);Game.tooltip.dynamic=1;Game.tooltip.draw(this,function(){return Game.crate(Game.UpgradesById[0],'store',undefined,undefined,1)();},'store');Game.tooltip.wobble();}" id="upgrade0" style="background-position:0px 0px;"></div>
```

Comment: I have also tried to use
    @FindBy (id = "upgrades")
    WebElement element;

Comment: Appreciate if you Share block of HTML instead of LInk.

Comment: @IshitaShah I've edited my post, is this what you mean?

Comment: Please share your initial trial code block, from where it got NullPointerException.

Comment: Check it is on frame or  not

Comment: In your game, when does the enabled upgrade appear to the user? In start it is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked on the website, your code requires modification.

Use the below code:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("upgrades"));
Actions acc=new Actions(driver);
acc.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
List<WebElement> upgrades = element.findElements(By.className("enabled"));
```

Let me know if this works for you.